# Non-admins on Mac Server, permissions and access

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, user-accounts

I've just recently set up a Mac OS X server (running on Snow Leopard) and I'm trying to create a user with regular (non-Admin) permissions but still allowing the user to login to their directory.

I'm wondering if this is possible? Can I have a user login on another mac computer and connect to the server? I'm trying to do all without using the terminal. The users want GUI access, meaning they'll connect to the server by click on the "Server" on the sidebar in Finder (on their computer) and then be taken to a folder on the mac server.

I might not be as clear, please ask if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm not an OS X person, so I couldn't tell you how to set this up, but it's absolutely possible with Samba shares. There should be info in this Apple's documentation. Apple may even have a different system they prefer, I'm sure looking through the documentation for "file sharing" or "file serving" would turn this up.

Comment: Do you want them to have access to their user directory from Finder, or do you want them to have remote desktop access (what one might call "GUI access")? What happens when you create a *Standard* user account and try to log in to the server? Have you actually enabled the desired service in *System Preferences » Sharing* (*File Sharing* or *Screen Sharing*)?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set up a file server in the OS X Server administrator (or that is what it used to be called). In there you can set up shares, and assign permissions to users. You can set up Apple (AFP) shares and Windows (SMB) shares. With AFP the shares will show up in the finder as long as all of the machines are on the same subnet.

Have a look at this:
http://images.apple.com/server/macosx/docs/File_Server_Admin_v10.6.pdf